# Access the value of Excel cells and not the formel in the cell

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, export-to-excel, spire.xls

I hope I will have the chance to find an appriate solution for my problem here .I'm trying to import the data from  an excel file in my c# program, I don't know why but I can't see the value at  that specified position. I can only see the code at this particular cell . May be something like C3*$B$2-$F$2.
I'm using the nuget Spire.XLS

Please I need help

I have tried to read the value in different ways but without succeed.

Comment: Documentation says something about FormulaDATATYPEValue properties you should use. Replace DATATYPE here with the names of the standard types in Excel

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the calculated values of formulas, you will need to use the **FormulaValue** property. Here is a simple example:

```
//Load an Excel file
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
workbook.LoadFromFile("Formulas.xlsx");

//Get the first worksheet
Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
//Read the calculated value of the formula in Cell B1
string calculatedValue = sheet.Range["B1"].FormulaValue.ToString();
```